# How do I reference a Perl hash in an array in a hash?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, reference, perl-data-structures

This is the code snippet I am working with:

```
my %photo_details = (
 'black_cat' => (
  ('size' => '1600x1200', 'position' => -25),
  ('size' => '1280x1024', 'position' =>  25),
  ('size' =>   '800x600', 'position' =>   0),
 ),
 'race_car' => (
  ('size' => '1600x1200', 'position' =>  10),
  ('size' =>   '800x600', 'position' =>   5),
 ),
);

my $photo = 'black_cat';

foreach my $photo_detail ($photo_details{$photo})
{
 my $size     = $photo_detail{'size'};
 my $position = $photo_detail{'position'};

 print ("size = $size, position = $position\n");
}
```

What I am expecting to get is:

> size = 1600x1200, position = -25
>
> size = 1280x1024, position = 25
>
> size = 800x600, position = 0

What I do get is:

> Use of uninitialized value $size in concatenation (.) or string at C:\Test.pl line 23.
>
> Use of uninitialized value $position in concatenation (.) or string at C:\Test.pl line 23.
>
> size = , position =

The foreach statement is clearly wrong as not only are there no values for $size and $position, it has only gone through the loop once instead of three times. I have tried all sorts of variants of variable prefixes and found none that work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is some updated code, with an explanation below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %photo_details = (
    'black_cat' => [
        {'size' => '1600x1200', 'position' => -25},
        {'size' => '1280x1024', 'position' =>  25},
        {'size' =>   '800x600', 'position' =>   0},
    ],
    'race_car' => [
        {'size' => '1600x1200', 'position' =>  10},
        {'size' =>   '800x600', 'position' =>   5},
    ],
);


print Dumper( %photo_details );
foreach my $name ( keys %photo_details ) {
    foreach my $photo_detail ( @{ $photo_details{$name} } ) {
        my $size     = $photo_detail->{'size'};
        my $position = $photo_detail->{'position'};

        print Dumper( $photo_details{$photo} );

        print ("size = $size, position = $position\n");
    }
}
```

I've replaced some of your parentheses with square and curly brackets. In Perl, square brackets give you a reference to an anonymous array, and curly brackets denote a reference to an anonymous hash. These are called anonymous because there's no explicit variable name for the anonymous array or hash.

As Perl data structures make you store a reference to a hash rather than the actual hash, you need these to construct the references. You can do this in two steps like this:

```
my @array = ( 1, 2, 3 );
my $array_ref = \@array;
my %hash = ( 'one' => 1, 'two' => 2, 'three' => 3 );
my $hash_ref = \%hash_ref;
```

To get data out of $array_ref and $hash_ref, you need the -> operator:

```
print $array_ref->[0], "\n";
print $hash_ref->{one}, "\n";
```

You don't need the quotes inside of the {} when referencing a hash key, although some people consider quotes on a hash key to be good practice.

I added an example of iteration over the entire data structure as an example rather than just looking at one reference. Here's the first line:

```
foreach my $name ( keys %photo_details ) {
```

The keys method returns all of the keys in a hash, so that you can get them in order. The next line iterates over all of the photo_detail hashrefs in %photo_details:

```
    foreach my $photo_detail ( @{ $photo_details{$photo} } ) {
```

The `@{ $photo_details{$photo} }` de-references the reference `$photo_details{$photo}` into an array, which you can iterate over it with foreach.

The last thing that I added is a call to [Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Dumper), a very useful module distributed with Perl that prints out data structures for you. This is very handy when building up data structures like this, as is its closely related cousin [Data::Dumper::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Data-Dumper-Simple/). This module is unfortunately not distributed with Perl, but I prefer its output as it includes variable names.

For some further reading about how to build up complex data structures using references, check out [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

Comment: Don't you mean `$photo_details{$name}`?

Comment: `my $hash_ref = \%hash_ref;` - that should be `\%hash`

Comment: I have just one question here: Can we call this data structure as `hash of array of hashes` for description purpose?

Answer (score 15):

First of all, always start every script or module with:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

You will get more warning messages and sooner, which greatly helps debugging.

I cannot duplicate your error: when I put that code into a file and run it with no additional flags, I get: `size = , position =`. <strike>There is no `$size` variable in the code you printed, so</strike>  the error message does not match.

Nevertheless, you are declaring your data structures incorrectly. Hashes and arrays can
only contain scalar values, not lists: so if you want to nest an array or
a hash, you need to make it a reference. See [perldoc perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html), [perldoc perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)
and [perldoc perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for more about data structures and references.

```
my %photo_details = (
    black_cat => [
        { size => '1600x1200', position => -25 },
        { size => '1280x1024', position =>  25 },
        { size => '800x600', position => 0 },
    ],
    race_car => [
        { size => '1600x1200', position =>  10 },
        { size => '800x600', position =>   5 },
    ],  
);

foreach my $photo_detail (@{$photo_details{black_cat}})
{
    my $size     = $photo_detail->{size};
    my $position = $photo_detail->{position};

    print ("size = $size, position = $position\n");
}
```

Comment: I'm confused, $size definitely **is** in the snippet he posted, you even carried it over to your code. What did you mean?

Comment: @lexu: yes, you're right; I was thinking the error might have come from using `$photo_detail->{$size}` vs `$photo_detail->{size}`. I totally overlooked the `my $size = ...` declaration. Nevertheless, I can't duplicate the OP's error. With strictures enabled, the code barfs earlier, at `%photo_detail` not being declared (due to the for loop not dereferencing the array).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The data structure definitely looks right now. However, if I try the code above I get "Global symbol "%photo_detail" requires explicit package name" on line 20 and 21. I read the docs (thanks for that) and changed the foreach statement to `[foreach my $photo_detail (@{%photo_details->{black_cat}})], changed `[$photo_detail{size}] to `[$photo_detail->{size}] and changed `[$photo_detail{position}] to `[$photo_detail->{position}] and it works but I get a "Using a hash as a reference is deprecated" on the foreach line. Any ideas?

Comment: @Ether I wasn't faulting your logic, only the statement abaut $size threw me of! The OP seems to be learning about the use of sigils and scopes .. both are confusing at first. (+1 from me for your good advice)

Comment: @TallGuy: looking up that warning message in 'perldoc perlwarn' is informative: you have a punctuation error on the foreach line.

Answer (score 2):

There's really only one thing you have to worry about, and that's the top level of the data structure. After that, you just use the right indexing syntax for each level:

If you have a regular hash, you access the key that you want then line up the additional indices for each level after it:

```
 %regular_hash = ...;
 $regular_hash{$key}[$index]{$key2};
```

If you have a reference, you do almost the same thing, but you have to start off with the initial dereference with an arrow, `->`, after the top-level reference. After that it's the same indexing sequence:

```
 $hash_ref = ...;
 $hash_ref->{$key}[$index]{$key2};
```

For all of the details, see [Intermediate Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596102067) where we explain reference syntax.